# Android app: informing users that an image is clickable

Tags: android, image, click

I have an Android app. In its help section, there are some images that are clickable and if clicked user can see more information. And there are images that are not clickable.

Other than adding a text above or below the images that are clickable and explicitly mentioning that, what are the best ways to show that an image is clickable?

On the web, this can be done by hovering when the mouse goes over the image, but is there something similar on Android for mobile apps?

Comment: Would be good if you added a screenshot to get a feel of how your elements are presented.

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed. Do you have any visuals? What happens when you tap the images? What is the purpose of the images that are tappable?

Comment: what is the goal of touching on the images? what is the consequence of that action?

Comment: On mobile, display by default the element that you show on hover, on the web. It can be a "+" that symbolize "more".

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of *similar* questions to yours, but I guess it's not quite a duplicate.

I feel like these questions would help you:

- [Make people understand they can click on a button in a flat design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/69671/67657)
- [Clickable and non-clickable images on the same page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/43829/67657)
- [How to make irregularly shaped objects / elements look clickable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/how-to-make-irregularly-shaped-objects-elements-look-clickable)
- [How to determine if button looks clickable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88412/how-to-determine-if-button-looks-clickable)

---

**Basically, just make the clickable elements stand out or add text/icons into or around the image that indicate the possible action.**

Or as said [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/88419/67657):

> Good affordance is really just mimicking how something would look in
>   the real world.

---

### Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Further similar questions:

- [Best way to communicate the action of a non-button control](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/best-way-to-communicate-the-action-of-a-non-button-control?rq=1)
- [Indicate tappable area on mobile](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25953/indicate-tappable-area-on-mobile)
- [How do I indicate that a subset of icons aren't clickable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56331/how-do-i-indicate-that-a-subset-of-icons-arent-clickable?rq=1)
- [How to modify an image to make it clear it's an image (and not a clickable button.)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60002/how-to-modify-an-image-to-make-it-clear-its-an-image-and-not-a-clickable-butto)